# Tkinter Canvas Problems

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm trying to change the layering of Tkinter Canvas widgets. With most widgets you can force the widget above other widgets by using the **lift** method. However, if I try the same on a Canvas widget I get an error.

Error :

```
TypeError: tag_raise() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aboveThis'
```

An Example of my Problem :

```
import Tkinter as Tk


root = Tk.Tk()

w, h = 200, 200

a = Tk.Canvas(root, bg='red', width=w, height=h)
a.grid(column=0, row=0)

b = Tk.Canvas(root, bg='blue', width=w, height=h)
b.grid(column=0, row=0)

a.lift(aboveThis=None)

root.mainloop()
```

If I do the same thing with Frame widgets, it works.

Example:

```
import Tkinter as Tk


root = Tk.Tk()

w, h = 200, 200

a = Tk.Frame(root, bg='red', width=w, height=h)
a.grid(column=0, row=0)

b = Tk.Frame(root, bg='blue', width=w, height=h)
b.grid(column=0, row=0)

a.lift(aboveThis=None)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas `lift()` method is an alias for `tag_raise()`, which is used to raise not the canvas itself but entities within the canvas.

I found this comment within the `Tkinter.py` source code:

```
# lower, tkraise/lift hide Misc.lower, Misc.tkraise/lift,
# so the preferred name for them is tag_lower, tag_raise
# (similar to tag_bind, and similar to the Text widget);
# unfortunately can't delete the old ones yet (maybe in 1.6)
```

If you replace `a.lift(aboveThis=None)` with `Tk.Misc.lift(a, aboveThis=None)` then the canvas widget is raised correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question because I was actually wanting to implement the equivalent of a tk statement like

```
canvas-pathName raise tagOrId ?aboveThis?
```

in order to raise individual canvas items to a particular z-position.  For those interested in the same thing, I'll just post my realization (after a little head-scratching) that this can be done in Python quite easily:

```
canvasObject.tag_raise(tagOrId, tagOrId2)
```

The second argument here just gets incorporated into the tk command line, and is then interpreted as an "aboveThis" value.